# Mining for 5 days at an avg of 19 Mh/s but not a single cent, is this normal?

Tags: mining-pools, gpu

Okay so i've been using ETHMiner and this cmd file to start it, and I've been mining for about 60-80 hours with and avg of 19 Mh/s and I havent recieved a single cent to my Jaxx wallet, is this normal?

Ive changed 0xMYWALLETID to my actual ID

```
setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0 setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100 setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1 setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100 setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100

ethminer -F http://eth-eu1.nanopool.org:8888/0xMYWALLETID -G

@Pause
```

I've been meaning to move over to Claymore Miner because im using my gtx 970 and I was following this guide https://eth.nanopool.org/help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your 19 Mh/s figure and the [Ethereum Mining Calculator](https://etherscan.io/ether-mining-calculator), you should be getting about 0.0040128644455329 ETH per hour, 0.0963087466927896 ETH per day or 0.3210288 ETH for 80 hours.

[image]

As you are mining with Nanopool, you should be able to check your statistics from their statistics page. Here is an example showing the account for a miner with 1,428.0 Mh/s - https://eth.nanopool.org/account/0x006a3f56690e4e59e5195a5946e2170afe32c978.

[image]

Use the link above, replacing your account in the URL, or enter your account on the top right of the nanopool statistics page, and you should see your miner's statistics. You should see your 19 Mh/s with some variation and your estimated earnings on the bottom right of the page. If not, you may have some configuration issue.

Comment: Oh thanks! I looked at my statistics and I saw that I've mined 
0.06389103 ETH and the minimum payout is 0.1, so once I reach 0.10000000 I should recieve the payment right? 
https://eth.nanopool.org/account/0xE7E116Fc14FFB2B67C3844c1cA28A25cA18E465E

Comment: Yup, you should get your payment once your account has accumulated more than 0.1 ETH during their periodic payment cycle. Don't know why you have only accumulated 0.06389103 when you have been mining for 60 to 80 hours. Is the 19 Mh/s showing up in your statistics page?

Comment: Seems like it skipped some parts, I looked over the statistics, I guess the internet cut out or something :/

Comment: "***0.3210288 ETH for 80 hours***" I doubt the OP will get 0.3 ether for 80 hours.